# Set dateTimePicker to Null if TextBox is certain value

Tags: c#, mysql, forms

I have a form that is linking to  a MySQL Database.
I want to have 3 **dateTimePickers** on the form to allow for three dates, however, if one is not selected, I want that Picker to show as blank, not the current date.

I am using the following code, and I get the error *"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll"* when I change the date in the Picker.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txtdateTimePicker1.Text != "1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM")
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        dateTimePicker1.Text = txtdateTimePicker1.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
        dateTimePicker1.Text = "";
    }
}
```

The Troubleshooting tips tells me to: *Make sure you do not have an infinite loop or infinite recursion.*

Basically, the textbox ***"txtdateTimePicker1"*** is filled with the date value on form load, and if it reads a certain date, ***"dateTimePicker1"*** shows a null value.

I THINK the loop happens because it looks at the value of **txtdateTimePicker1**, then changes the value of **dateTimePicker1**, thus causing it to once again trigger the ValueChanged event, but I do now know of any other way to trigger the event properly. Is there a way to use a While loop instead? Something that says:

```
While (txtdateTimePicker1.Text == "1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM")
{
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
    dateTimePicker1.Text = "";
}
```

**but**

```
if (txtdateTimePicker1.Text != "1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM")
{
    dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
    dateTimePicker1.Text = txtdateTimePicker1.Text;
}
```

I am really new to While Loops, and I did study them some, and I understand HOW they work, but I don't really know the syntax.

OR... since the textbox is filled when the form is initialized, is there a way I can trigger the code I need a different way?

Also, I know that I may not be using Best Practice Methods here, that will come later. I need to try to get this functional, and the rest of my form works properly, except this one event. Please don't berate me for not using the right methods, instead, please help me work through the issue at hand.

#### System Info:

- Windows 8.1
- .NET Framework 4.5
- Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate
- MySQL 5.6 for Visual Studio

#### Full Form Code (Minus MySQL Connection String:)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace _2014BillOfMaterials
{
    public partial class BillofMaterialsRevisions : Form
    {
        public BillofMaterialsRevisions(string s)
        {
            if (s != "- Select a Job -")
            {
                string server = "192.168.1.149";
                string database = "####";
                string userid = "iuapp";
                string password = "iuapp";
                string str;
                str = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + userid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

                MySqlConnection con = null;

                con = new MySqlConnection(str);

                MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(str);
                MySqlDataAdapter jobNumber = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM jobnumbers where jobNumber = '" + s + "'", myconn);

                DataTable dtJobNumber = new DataTable("jobnumbers");
                DataSet dtJobNumber2 = new DataSet();
                jobNumber.Fill(dtJobNumber);

                InitializeComponent();
                this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM jobnumbers where jobNumber = '" + s + "'", myconn);
                adapter.Fill(dtJobNumber2);
                textBox2.Text = dtJobNumber2.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
                textBox1.Text = dtJobNumber2.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();
                textBox3.Text = dtJobNumber2.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString();
                textBox4.Text = dtJobNumber2.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();

                txtdateTimePicker1.Text = dtJobNumber2.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                txtdateTimePicker2.Text = dtJobNumber2.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
                txtdateTimePicker3.Text = dtJobNumber2.Tables[0].Rows[0][9].ToString();


                lblJobNumber.Text = s + " Revisions";
                label10.Text = s;
            }
            else
            {
                //Show Error MessageBox
                MessageBox.Show("Please Select a Job.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            }

        }

        private void BillofMaterialsRevisions_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {                        
            string server = "192.168.1.149";
            string database = "####";
            string userid = "iuapp";
            string password = "iuapp";
            string str;
            str = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + database + ";" + "UID=" + userid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

            MySqlConnection myconn2 = new MySqlConnection(str);
            MySqlConnection con = null;

            con = new MySqlConnection(str);
            con.Open();

            string date1 = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string date2 = dateTimePicker2.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            string date3 = dateTimePicker3.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

            var cmd = new MySqlCommand("Insert into jobnumbers(id, jobNumber, IssuedDate, IssuedInitials, RevADate, RevAInitials, RevBDate, RevBInitials) SELECT DISTINCT '" +
                textBox4.Text + "', '" + 
                label10.Text + "', '" +
                date1 + "', '" +
                textBox2.Text + "', '" +
                date2 + "', '" +
                textBox1.Text + "', '" +
                date3 + "', '" +
                textBox3.Text +
                "' " +
                "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id =  '" + textBox4.Text + "' " +
                ", jobNumber = '" + label10.Text + "' " +
                ", IssuedDate = '" + date1 + "' " +
                ", IssuedInitials = '" + textBox2.Text + "' " +
                ", RevADate = '" + date2 + "' " +
                ", RevAInitials = '" + textBox1.Text + "' " +
                ", RevBDate = '" + date3 + "' " +
                ", RevBInitials = '" + textBox3.Text + "'", con);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtdateTimePicker1.Text == "1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                dateTimePicker1.Text = txtdateTimePicker1.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = " ";
                dateTimePicker1.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private void dateTimePicker2_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtdateTimePicker2.Text != "" || txtdateTimePicker2.Text != "1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                dateTimePicker2.Text = txtdateTimePicker2.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = " ";
                dateTimePicker2.Text = "";
            }
        }

        private void dateTimePicker3_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txtdateTimePicker3.Text != "" || txtdateTimePicker3.Text != "1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM")
            {
                dateTimePicker3.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
                dateTimePicker3.Text = txtdateTimePicker3.Text;
            }
            else
            {
                dateTimePicker3.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
                dateTimePicker3.CustomFormat = " ";
                dateTimePicker3.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `"" (Empty)` to `Text` property is not allowed because `Text` property should be a *valid* DateTime object. Check out its [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt6y6733%28v=vs.90%29.ASPX).

A possibility to fix this is to disable the `DateTimePicker` control and enable it back when needed.

Use:

```
dateTimePicker1.Enabled = True;  // enables it
dateTimePicker1.Enabled = False; // disable it
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: If I do that, and I submit the dates to my Database, what will happen? Won't I get an error message because it is trying to get a value that it can't access?

Comment: The value in control is still readable, but not editable. If the value is not selected it should either store NULL or current timestamp in database depending upon what is suitable. No errors should be raise, because it will be disable iff it is either not required or user hasn't choose any option that needs a corresponding date value.

Comment: That really does not help me then, because the reason I am trying to add a null value is because by default, it adds a current timestamp, and that is not at all what I want. It must be different. However, I am thinking about adding a simple Checkbox that will allow me to enable and disable the fields, and then using an if statement based on the selection of that to set the values I need.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done is created a Checkbox that changes the CustomFormat property and Text Value of the dateTimePicker and associated textBoxes, and I have changed the datatype of the field in my Database from DATE to Varchar, and that has seemed to work properly. This particular app has to work in a certain way, and these tables are not going to be used for extensive reports that would require the Dates to be in a specific datatype.

I realize that there are many other, better ways to accomplish this, but I am on a bit of a time constraint, so this works for now.

NeverHopeless gave me a solution that, under different circumstances would have worked, but for this project, it simply wasn't enough.

Here is the code for the Checkboxes:

```
public void CheckCheckBoxes2()
{
    if (checkBox2.Checked == false)
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        dateTimePicker2.CustomFormat = " ";
        dateTimePicker2.Text = null;
        dateTimePicker2.Enabled = false;
        textBox2.Text = null;
        textBox2.Enabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        dateTimePicker2.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        dateTimePicker2.Enabled = true;
        textBox2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```